# Team City - URL Trigger - Not working

Tags: teamcity

We are using TeamCity Professional 9.1.7, We have setup automated tests in Team City which using Selenium.

In order to invoke the test suite we are leveraging the URL build trigger.

Once the application is deployed on the target server we have an URL which will return the installed version and date time stamp on the server everyday.

When we made an attempt to hit URL manually the version and date time is getting returned. And there is connectivity between TeamCity and deployed server.

We have configured the URL as : abc.XXX/sample.txt and TeamCity is complaining with the following message:

```
URL build trigger failed with error: URL abc.XXX/sample.txt: null 
Hide stacktrace

jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.BuildTriggerException: URL build trigger failed with error: URL https://abc.XXX/sample.txt: null 
at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.url.UrlBuildTrigger$2.makeTriggerException(UrlBuildTrigger.java:117)
at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.async.impl.AsyncPolledBuildTrigger.processJobResults(AsyncPolledBuildTrigger.java:146)
at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.async.impl.AsyncPolledBuildTrigger.triggerBuild(AsyncPolledBuildTrigger.java:60)
at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildTriggersChecker$4.run(BuildTriggersChecker.java) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.util.NamedThreadFactory.executeWithNewThreadName(NamedThreadFactory.java:89) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildTriggersChecker.callTrigger(BuildTriggersChecker.java:32) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildTriggersChecker.access$1100(BuildTriggersChecker.java:65) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildTriggersChecker$BuildTriggersGroup.processTriggers(BuildTriggersChecker.java:37)
at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildTriggersChecker.triggerBuilds(BuildTriggersChecker.java:50) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildServerRunner$4.doSomething(BuildServerRunner.java) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildServerRunner$BuildServerWorker.runAction(BuildServerRunner.java:47)
at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildServerRunner$BuildServerWorker.run(BuildServerRunner.java:9) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.async.DetectionException: URL https://abc.XXX/sample.txt: null 
at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.url.UrlBuildTrigger.createThrowableResult(UrlBuildTrigger.java:203) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.url.UrlBuildTrigger.access$700(UrlBuildTrigger.java:39) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.url.UrlBuildTrigger$2$1.perform(UrlBuildTrigger.java:169) 
at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.async.impl.AsyncPolledBuildTrigger$2.run(AsyncPolledBuildTrigger.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
... 1 more 
Caused by: jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.url.ResourceHashProviderException: URL https://abc.XXX/sample.txt: null 
at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.url.HttpResourceHashProvider.getResourceHash(HttpResourceHashProvider.java:115)
at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.url.UrlBuildTrigger$2$1.perform(UrlBuildTrigger.java:149) 
... 4 more 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please help.

Comment: can you update the Teamcity version?

Comment: That is currently under consideration due to new version availability but is that the issue because what i found that some of the URL trigger work and some didnt

Answer (score 0):

Finally the issue resolved, our URL was having underscore `_` in it. There seems to be a constraint/defect with team city that the URL trigger cant have underscore `_` in it.

We replaced all `_` with `-` and it worked.